# Windows 8 Font Stack

Tags: windows-8, fonts, truetype-fonts, font-faces, windows-8-fonts

Are there any new fonts in Windows 8 compared to Windows 7?

Is there any place I can get a complete/diff list, perhaps even with some previews?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are new fonts in Windows 8.

There is a blog post detailing the new fonts - [Script and Font Support in the Windows 8 Consumer Preview](http://www.siao2.com/2012/03/19/10284834.aspx).

---

Note that some letters of Segoe UI have been redesigned, as shown ([source at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700394.aspx)):

## In Windows 7: [image]

## In Windows 8: [image]

---

The following table lists scripts newly supported in Windows 8, and associated fonts:

```
New scripts Script origin   Fonts               Comments on language usage
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Glagolitic  Europe          Segoe UI Symbol     Historic
Gothic      Europe          Segoe UI    Symbol  Historic
Old Hangul  East Asia       Malgun Gothic       Historic (Korean texts)
Old Italic  Europe  Segoe UI Symbol             Historic
Lisu        China           Segoe UI            Lisu
Myanmar     Southeast Asia  Myanmar Text        Myanmar, Shan, Karen
N'Ko        Africa          Ebrima              N'Ko and other Manding languages
Orkhon      China           Segoe UI Symbol     Historic
```

From the blog:

> The UI font changes are as follows:
>
> - Ebrima font: updated to add support for Ethiopic and NʼKo scripts
> - Gadugi font: new font for Canadian Aboriginal Syllabics and Cherokee scripts
> - Microsoft JhengHei UI: new font for Traditional Chinese script
> - Microsoft YaHei UI: new font for Simplified Chinese script
> - Nirmala UI: new font for South Asian scripts (Bangla, Devanagari, Gujarati, Malayalam, Odia, Telugu)
> - Segoe UI (certain weights): updated to add support for Arabic, Armenian, Georgian (Mkhedruli), Georgian Khutsuri, Hebrew scripts

---

Some fonts have been updated:

> Comic Sans gets a legitimate italic and bold italic - [New Typefaces for Windows 8](http://donnedwards.openaccess.co.za/2012/03/new-typefaces-for-windows-8.html)

Further sources:

- http://donnedwards.openaccess.co.za/2012/03/new-typefaces-for-windows-8.html
- http://www.infinality.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=242

Comment: I prefer the Windows 8 re-design of Segoe UI. But it seems that there are no new (latin-based) font-faces, just new scripts. Is that right, or am I reading it wrong?